# Как наложить на фото эффект в CSS, и забрать эту картинку с этим же эффектом?

Tags: html, css, filter, webkit

Если я применяю -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); картинка будет с фильтром только в рамках сайта. Можно ли, допустим скачивать эту картинку с этим же эффектом? Или, может, есть какие то другие способы реализации этой идеи? По сути, делаю простое приложение для наложения эффектов

Comment: Вам необходимо обрабатывать фотографию на стороне сервера и отдавать пользователю уже обработанную версию.

Comment: Лучше все манипуляции с картинкой реализовать в `canvas` и далее сохранить ее на сервере и отдать... без сервера ни как...